# How to get ownership of a moved value back from a closure?

Tags: rust

Consider the following program:

```
fn primes_up_to(n: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut ans = Vec::with_capacity(n);

    if n < 2 {
        return ans;
    }

    ans.push(2);

    // https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.22.0/book/first-edition/closures.html#closures-and-their-environment
    // The closure needs ownership of vec to access elements
    let is_prime = |n: usize| -> bool {
        for x in ans {
            if x * x > n {
                break;
            }

            if n % x == 0 {
                return false;
            }
        }

        true
    };

    let mut i = 3;
    while i <= n {
        if is_prime(i) {
            ans.push(i);
        }

        i += 2;
    }

    ans
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", primes_up_to(23));
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2d005ebdcf76dfb732958b514a5755b5&version=stable))

Compiling the code above gives these compilation errors:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `is_prime`
  --> src/main.rs:28:12
   |
28 |         if is_prime(i) {
   |            ^^^^^^^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
   |
note: closure cannot be invoked more than once because it moves the variable `ans` out of its environment
  --> src/main.rs:13:18
   |
13 |         for x in ans {
   |                  ^^^

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `ans`
  --> src/main.rs:29:13
   |
12 |     let is_prime = |n: usize| -> bool {
   |                    ------------------ value moved (into closure) here
...
29 |             ans.push(i);
   |             ^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `ans` has type `std::vec::Vec<usize>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `ans`
  --> src/main.rs:35:5
   |
12 |     let is_prime = |n: usize| -> bool {
   |                    ------------------ value moved (into closure) here
...
35 |     ans
   |     ^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `ans` has type `std::vec::Vec<usize>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I know a potential solution would be to pass an immutable reference to `ans` (`&ans`) to `is_prime`. What is the idiomatic way for ownership of `ans` to pass into `is_prime` and come back out when `is_prime` exits every time I call `is_prime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to get ownership of a moved value back from a closure

**You don't**.

Once ownership is transferred, it's gone. The only way to "get it back" is to have the thing that now owns it transfer it back. Some types have an `into_inner` method for this exact reason. Other types have equivalent methods.

A closure's only interface, by definition, is the ability to invoke it. There are no other possibilities for methods.

You could return the captured value when you are done, but that doesn't help in your case because you need to call the closure multiple times — you couldn't return it because it might be needed in the future.

Comment: > you couldn't return it because it might be needed in the future.

In my opinion, if a closure return its captured values, then it's fine to release the ownership of the value, when invoked again, just capture the value again. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: @JiacaiLiu I don't completely follow your suggestion. If the closure needs a value to work and returns ownership of that value, then the closure can no longer exist. Yes, you could then recreate the closure with the value, but that would be a bunch of repeated code and kind of ignores the point of the closure, so I don't see why it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code, in:

```
for x in ans {
```

> closure cannot be invoked more than once because it moves the variable
>   `ans` out of its environment:

The **iterator invalidates** with each `ans.push(i);`

So you should borrow the `ans` exactly in this line:

```
if is_prime(i) {
```

then give it back to the next line:

```
ans.push(i);
```

The solution is to pass it as an argument:

```
fn primes_up_to(n: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut ans = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    if n < 2 {
        return ans;
    }
    ans.push(2);
    let is_prime = |n: usize, v: &[usize]| -> bool {
        for x in v {
            if x * x > n {
                break;
            }
            if n % x == 0 {
                return false;
            }
        }
        true
    };
    let mut i: usize = 3;
    while i <= n {
        if is_prime(i, &ans) {
            ans.push(i);
        }
        i += 2;
    }
    ans
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", primes_up_to(23));
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a81fe155fa51a4f3a2eddf31138e1b2b&version=stable))

Or try this, it has same `ASM` footprint as above in release mode on the nightly channel:

```
fn primes_up_to(n: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut ans = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    if n < 2 {
        return ans;
    }
    ans.push(2);
    let is_prime = |n: usize, v: &Vec<usize>| -> bool {
        for x in v {
            if x * x > n {
                break;
            }
            if n % x == 0 {
                return false;
            }
        }
        true
    };
    let mut i: usize = 3;
    while i <= n {
        if is_prime(i, &ans) {
            ans.push(i);
        }
        i += 2;
    }
    ans
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", primes_up_to(23));
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=785fc72f52c599d1e735fe659d571665&version=stable))

output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
```

And see: [Move semantics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/ownership.html#move-semantics) and [Borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/references-and-borrowing.html#borrowing)

Comment: At this point the closure doesn't capture anything. So it can be replaced by a function `fn is_prime(n: usize, v: &[usize]) -> bool { //...`

Comment: `is_prime(i, &ans)` is more concise. `Vec<T>` implements `Deref<Target=[T]>`, so `&ans` is coerced to `&[usize]`.

Comment: While this does fix the example code I don't think it actually answers the question(s).

Comment: @Stefan : explanations Added

Comment: @a-r I get the idea behind passing the vector as an argument to the closure to make this work. What I specifically want to understand is that if the closure does not modify the vector, shouldn't there be a way for it to capture only a reference of the data and not get the ownership, because the closure doesn't need the ownership it is getting here as it isn't doing anything to modify the data the vector stores, and adding a reference to the vector as a parameter invalidates the purpose of the closure in the first place.

Comment: For a contrast, closures in C++ can capture values by copying or taking a reference. So in a C++ equivalent program, the closure would do its job by just taking a reference of the vector.